# Posting a comment on the news feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-comments

Hey all i am using the following code to post to a posting on my news feed:

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'fileUpload' => true,
  'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $access_token   = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $user_profile   = $facebook->api('/me');
    $comment        = $facebook ->api('/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/comments', 
                                 'POST', 
                                    array(
                                      'access_token' => $access_token,
                                      'message' => 'testing!'
                                    )
                                );
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo ($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

<?php if ($user): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes, email, read_mailbox, read_requests, user_online_presence, friends_online_presence, manage_notifications, publish_actions, publish_stream, user_likes, user_photos, user_status, user_videos, read_insights'
    );
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}

?>

<?php print_r($user_profile); ?>
```

For some reason i get this error:

**OAuthException: (#221) Photo not visible**

And i have no idea since i am posting a text comment and not even an image??

If i comment out the code line **$comment       = $facebook ->api('/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/comments', 
                                     'POST', 
                                        array(
                                          'access_token' => $access_token,
                                          'message' => 'testing!'
                                        )
                                    );** it works just fine (as in, displays my info with **user_profile**). I've tried reading over the page that tells you how to use the comments [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments/) and i do - it just doesn't seem to want to work?

What am i missing???

**update**

using the graph API i was able to do the same thing i am trying to do via PHP so i **know** it works...:

[image]

Comment: Is there suppose to be a space between $facebook and ->api(...  ?

Comment: Is the object you want to post a comment upon itself a photo?

Comment: @CBroe yes its a photo a friend has posted. Im commenting about it. I can leave a comment like normal on facebook below it just fine. It just doesnt seem to work in code.

Comment: @halfnibble nope, still the same error even fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but...

First, for tests the same enviroment, you have to use your app token, not the **Graph API Explorer**. Otherwise, you're testing the API with *all the permissions*.

[image]

Second, your problem must be a permission thing (that's why it's working on the API Explorer). You should:

1. Ask for *publish_permission* on the login (not recommended) or,
2. Ask for *publish_permission* when the user is ready to send the comment.

   - More information about this: [Optimizing Permissions Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#optimizing)
   - Here the permissions that you need: [Publishing Comments
     Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/comments#publish)

As a general rule, when you see a **OAuthException**, you are having a permission issue.

If the post is **photo** type, you're going to need a *user_photos* permission.